# Loop para determinar o menor valor digitado

Tags: python, if, lógica, while

Estou com dificuldade em criar repetições para tirar o menor valor de uma determinada situação.

Por exemplo, um programa que registre preço de produtos no qual tenho que informar o menor valor e o maior, vi em alguns lugares que declararia duas variáveis como `menorv` e `maiorv`, depois colocaria um `if` igualando a 1 e então fazia as condições que seria tipo:

```
maiorv = menorv = 0
while True:
    n = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$ '))
    if n == 1:
      maiorv = menorv = n
    else:
        if n > maiorv:
           maiorv = n
        if n < menorv:
           menorv = n
    continuar = ' '
    while continuar not in 'SN':
        continuar = str(input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ')).upper().strip()[0]
    if continuar == 'N':
        break
print(f'O maior valor é {maiorv}')
print(f'O menor valor é  {menorv}')
```

O valor sempre retorna zero, teriam uma dica de qual lógica usar nesses casos? E o que estou errando para retornar 0? Eu já ouvi falar sobre um float e -float mas não entendi muito bem sobre.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente, a estrutura condicional igualando a 1 serve para identificar em qual iteração o laço de repetição se encontra.

No caso, é necessário criar um contador (que vou chamar de `cont`) e incrementar em um no final de cada iteração.

**Observação: Este código foi feito para a versão 3.6 do Python ou superior.**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

maiorv = menorv = 0
cont = 1
while True:
    n = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$ '))
    if cont == 1:
        maiorv = menorv = n
    else:
        if n > maiorv:
            maiorv = n
        if n < menorv:
            menorv = n
    continuar = ' '
    while continuar not in 'SN':
        continuar = str(input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ')).upper().strip()[0]
    if continuar == 'N':
        break
    cont = cont + 1
print(f'O maior valor e {maiorv}')
print(f'O menor valor e  {menorv}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Mudando o nome da variável de `n` para `preco` talvez fique um pouco mais "didático" para explicar (e também porque [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad)):

```
maiorv = menorv = 0
while True:
    preco = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$ '))
    if preco == 1:
      maiorv = menorv = preco
    else:
        if preco > maiorv:
           maiorv = preco
        if preco < menorv:
           menorv = preco
    etc...
```

Ou seja, **se o preço digitado for igual a 1** você faz com que o maior e menor preço sejam 1. Isso está errado porque, no caso em que o `1` seja o último valor digitado (por exemplo, o usuário digita vários valores, depois digita `1` e depois escolhe "N" para não continuar), então tanto o maior quanto o menor serão 1. Isso faz com que todos os valores anteriores sejam ignorados. Esse `if` não faz sentido, remova-o.

Outro detalhe é que `menorv` começa em zero. Então qualquer valor positivo que for digitado (1, 2, 3, qualquer outro valor positivo) **nunca será menor que zero**, então nunca entrará no `if preco < menorv`. Somente se você digitar um valor negativo, aí ele será menor que zero e entrará neste `if` (mas pela lógica do programa, um preço negativo não faria sentido). Então se você só digitar valores positivos, nunca entrará no `if` e no fim `menorv` será zero.

Sendo assim, uma solução é fazer com que `menorv` comece com o maior valor possível, assim qualquer coisa que for digitada será com certeza menor que ele. O "maior valor possível", no caso, é "infinito", que pode ser obtido usando-se [`float('inf')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

A mesma lógica vale para `maiorv`: ele deve começar com o menor valor possível, assim qualquer coisa que for digitada será com certeza maior que ele (e uma opção é usar o "infinito negativo", que pode ser obtido com `float('-inf')` ou `-float('inf')`).

E tire o `if preco == 1`, como já explicado:

```
maiorv = float('-inf') # infinito negativo
menorv = float('inf') # infinito
while True:
    preco = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$ '))
    if preco > maiorv:
       maiorv = preco
    if preco < menorv:
       menorv = preco
    continuar = ' '
    while continuar not in 'SN':
        continuar = input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ').upper().strip()[0]
    if continuar == 'N':
        break
```

Repare também que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário. Faça apenas `input(...)`.

Por fim, sugiro que aprenda a fazer o [teste de mesa](/q/220474/112052) e a [debugar o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052), que erros de lógica como esse podem ser facilmente detectados.

---

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468543/112052) guarda os valores em uma lista e depois usa [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) e [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) para obter o maior e menor.

Também funciona, claro, mas há o detalhe de que cada uma dessas chamadas percorre toda a lista (ou seja, a lista é percorrida duas vezes, uma para verificar o maior, e outra para o menor).

Claro que para uma quantidade pequena de números, a diferença é irrelevante. Mas se você não precisa guardar todos os números digitados, eu não criaria a lista para este caso. E de qualquer forma é interessante saber que existem funções prontas na linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um algoritmo que avalie qual é o `maior` e o `menor` valor dentre os valores digitados.

Para resolver esta questão, podemos implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
valores = list()
while True:
    n = float(input('Digite o valor do produto: R$ '))
    valores.append(n)

    resp = input('Quer continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input('Quer continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        r = sorted(valores, reverse=True)
        menorv = r[-1]
        maiorv = r[0]
        print(f'O menor valor é: R$ {menorv:.2f}')
        print(f'O maior valor é: R$ {maiorv:.2f}')
        break
```

Observe que neste algoritmo foi implementado um `laço de repetição` que capturará os valores digitados. Posteriormente, cada um desses valores são inseridos na lista `valores`.

Observe também que foi implementado um segundo bloco `while`. Este, por sua vez, avalia a resposta do usuário `[S/N]` e toma uma decisão. De acordo com a resposta o programa é encerrado ou executado novamente.

Observe que quando decidimos encerrar, o algoritmo nos exibe o `menor` e o `maior` valor para, em seguida, finalizar a execução.